# Did saraswati/savitri slay vritra or vetra according to rigveda?

Tags: rig-veda, asuras, saraswati

According to wikipedia article of [Vritra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vritra) -

> In one verse of a Rig-Vedic hymn eulogising Sarasvati, she is portrayed as the one who slayed Vritra. Mention of this occurs nowhere else.

The verse the article mentioning is 6.61

I think it's not vritra but son of Vritra, Vetra with similar name
as this story is found in Varaha Purana and Mahabharata too

As per wiki article of [Gayatri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gayatri)

> She further developed into a fierce goddess who could even slay a demon. According to Varaha Purana and Mahabharata, Goddess Gayatri slayed the demon Vetrasura, the son of Vritra and river Vetravati, on a Navami day.

Does Rigveda call the demon vritra or vetra?

Comment: Do some research effort from your side. Did you read wikipedia article you quoted carefully?

Comment: There are [7] [8] in the brackets. They are exact references. There is verse number in the verse. Also quote correct article link and removed brackets while pasting here.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma now my question isn't about verse no but info in the hymn.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with indologists here. Griffith didn't say it is Sarasvati who killed Vritrasura. The paragraph about them is unnecessary. It is just showing your dislike towards them which is not needed in the question.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma so I should remove the last paragraph?

Comment: Vetra is the son of Vritrasura in his next life as mentioned in the Varaha Purana.

Comment: @Anisha: If we consider the names mentioned in Rig Veda such as Indra or Varuna or Saraswati, etc, as epithets, but not as real names, then we can get a different picture.  Saraswati can be viewed as flow of BLISS and Indra is the strength of that BLISS.  So both represent different sides of the same thing.  Then we can understand that Indra or Varuna or Saraswati, etc, as one and the same.  In part of Rig Veda Vishnu was eulogised as spreading into entire universe in 3 strides and in another part, Indra was praised as to covering the universe immediately after his birth.

Answer (score 4):

> उत स्या न: सरस्वती घोरा हिरण्यवर्तनी: | वृत्रघ्नी वष्टि सुष्टुतिम
>   ||[**RV. 6.61.7**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv06061.htm) ||
>
> uta syā naḥ sarasvatī ghorā hiraṇyavartaniḥ |  vṛtraghnī vaṣṭi
>   suṣṭutim ||
>
> 7 Yea, this divine Sarasvatī, terrible with her golden path,
>   Foe-slayer, claims our eulogy.

The verse you quoted in the question isn't actually  saying that Devi Saraswati is the slayer of Vritra. But in the sukta  she is said to have  equal strength  like Indra   and also  destroyer of enemies like him  , who is slayer of vritrasura.

The word used in the mantra is Vrutaghni (वृतघ्नी) . This word is used to as a name of Indra here and to denote him and his  deed  ,it is also used  to show her equality with Indra in strength. But not actually to denote that she is slayer of Vritra.

The two other translators translated the word as as  destroyer of enemies and destroyer of enemies  having equal strength like Indra and similarly the Griffith one.

---

See the [**footnote**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vritra#cite_note-7) 7

> Griffith replaces the "Vritra-slayer" found in the Sanskrit (verse 7)
>   with a generic "foe-slayer".

---

Here is [**Arya Samaj**](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=dmVkaWNncmFudGgub3JnfHd3d3xneDoxMGU5YjA0ZTU1MzUzMDBj) translation . See Page No. 52. And below is AWGP translation , both are in Hindi.

[image: AWGP]